# Could the edit character limit be lowered?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, editing

I would often like to add syntax highlighting to code blocks pasted in questions. But in most cases this consists solely of putting a single `rust` or `json`, which is less than the minimum number of characters for an edit (i.e. six chars). I believe these kinds of edits are valuable though and I don't want to include any unnecessary changes just to fill the limit. Could we lower it?